# Developing an iPhone app like a simplified version of the address book

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm new to iPhone development, so I need some help developing the following app. I'm not sure where to start.

The app is very simple, it's like a simplified version of the address book that came with the iPhone:

- a screen shows a list of all items in a list view
- list can be filtered through search
- list can also be favorites or unfavorites
- selecting an item will take the user to another screen with more detailed information (a pic, location,)

the data should be stored in an xml file.

Can you point me to the right path?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to iPhone development :) Whilst there are lots of tutorials online I'd definitely recommend following the Beginning iPhone 3 Development: Exploring the iPhone SDK http://apress.com/book/view/1430224592 book. It's a great introduction to iPhone development and will cover many of the points you've mentioned.

Comment: Actually I have that book too! CS193P and that book taught me loads!

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty basic stuff. There are samples for all of that on developer.apple.com

As an alternative approach, Stanford university published their introduction to iPhone programming course CS193P on iTunesU which wil teach you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend checking out the stanford iPhone programming course on iTunes University.  This is what got me started - the lectures are very good and the assignments will help you understand basic concepts.  https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/iphone-application-development-winter-2010/id384233225